# Should I use the system or separate pipenv for multiple Python versions?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv

I have multiple versions of Python installed on my machine using `pyenv`.

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.16
  3.4.9
  3.5.7
  3.6.8
* 3.7.2
```

For each I need to create virtualenvs using `pipenv`. Should I use the system `pipenv` for this (installed with a package manager or `pip`) or a separate `pipenv` per interpreter (installed with `pip`). What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how I do it. My system requires certain versions of Python 2/3 because I install stuff that needs these dependencies.

*All* of my own projects run in their own virtual environments, which contain their own sets of dependent modules. So when I create a new project for myself, I build that off the system Python:

```
> mkdir my-project
> cd my-project
> python3.7 -m venv .
```

…or any other Python version I need (although I usually stick with Python 3).

Comment: I prefer to use `pipenv` for managing virtualenvs and dependencies.  But I guess it should work the same.